# Each Dot Color in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to edit this program [DotsPanel.java](http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~diana/csi1102/Examples/chap07/DotsPanel.java) to on each click, it gives the first click red dot and the second click gives green dot.

I tried using inside the `while` loop this code :

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
if (i%2==0) page.setColor(Color.green);
else page.setColor(Color.red);
}
```

And I tried to use `if-else` statement, I have `private int c=0;` :

```
        if(c%2==0){
            page.setColor(Color.yellow);
            c++;
        }

        else{
            page.setColor(Color.red);
            c++;
        }
```

The colors changed but at every third click all the dots change colors, which I want to stay the same colors.

Nothing is working here, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? What do you expecting it to do, and what does it do instead? Your for-loop does nothing other than setting the graphics color to red when it exits the loop at  i=999

Comment: Post your [mre] code in the forum.

Comment: @FredK at the first click the first dot is green, at the second click the new other dot is red, the third is green, fourth is red...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the paintComponent method:

```
  boolean b = true;
  while (pointIterator.hasNext())
  {
     page.setColor( b ? Color.green : Color.red);
     b = !b;
     Point drawPoint = (Point) pointIterator.next();
     page.fillOval (drawPoint.x - RADIUS, drawPoint.y - RADIUS,
                    RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);
  }
```